# Test CheckBox on NestedTree fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, wicket, wicket-6

I built my tree application based on the NestedTree example from [www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/tree/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.tree.NestedTreePage), but i'm struggling at testing this component using WicketTester.

With WicketTester i trigger the AJAX event on the CheckBox:

```
tester.executeAjaxEvent("path:to:checkbox", "onclick");
```

The AjaxCheckBox `onUpdate` event is fired as well, but it's model doesn't change.

A simple page with an AjaxCheckBox and PropertyModel works fine, the model changes as expected:

```
add(new AjaxCheckBox("check", new PropertyModel<>(this, "checked")));
```

Is it impossible to test this component with WicketTester?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set a value for the checkbox, just executing a click won't send any input in the request:

```
formTester.setValue("path:to:checkbox", true);
```